# How to establish ssh port forwarding inside docker container

Tags: docker, ssh-tunnel

I am learning docker containers so that I can build a LAMP container that is deployable to any of my developers such that it will provide a complete, ready-to-run development environment for my company's application suite. I am 99% complete and working but one thing I can't figure out is how to establish an ssh client connection inside the container so that it maps specific ports to our corporate network that is required by my container apps. This is needed because some developers are outside the corporate network and some are inside. I am well-versed in SSH, public/private keys, etc just not docker. How should this be accomplished using Docker?

Comment: do this documentation help? https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/

Comment: Unfortunately no. That document describes how to setup the container network. What I need will be inside the container in one of the images.

Comment: can you give a more specific / detailed example?

Comment: My webserver image is using php:7.4.25-apache-buster. In my Dockerfile I copying over SSH keys and a bash script that starts an SSH connection to my authentication server (Active Directory). How can I get that script to start automatically when I run "docker-compose up"?

Comment: have you tried using ```docker exec``` or adding ```RUN``` command in your dockerfile?

Comment: That might have worked eventually. I ended up building a new container just for the SSH tunnels. This worked fine.